# Difference between "New Folder", "New Source Folder" and "New Package"?

Tags: eclipse

When you right-click on a project in eclipse, what is the difference between "New Folder", "New Source Folder" and "New Package"? They all seem to do the same thing and the reference does not say much.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*New folder* creates a new folder inside a project.

*New source folder* creates a new folder iside a project, and adds this folder to the set of source folders of the project. Eclipse will compile the files in this folder.

*New package* creates a new Java package inside a source folder. It also creates the folder associated with the package, of course.